# Trying to disable edit button based on gridview result - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a gridview that I need to disable the "Edit" linkbutton when it's not the current week.  I have accomplished this in my code, but when I got that to work, it took away the update and cancel functionality, giving me a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when i press update or cancel. I'll post the entire code, but I want to point out this is the code that makes the disabling work and the code that I can comment out and get the update and cancel functions to work again:

```
    'Disable edit button if not the current week
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim lbl As Label
        lbl = CType(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("lblWeekStart"), Label)
        If lbl.Text <> currentDay Then
            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

More specifically, it errors out on this line b/c of lbl.Text:

If lbl.Text <> currentDay Then

But here's the entire sub routine:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Get User's Name
    Dim lblFtrSubmitter As Label = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblFtrSubmitter")
    lblFtrSubmitter.Text = Context.User.Identity.Name

    'Get Time Recorded
    Dim lblFtrTimeRecorded As Label = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblFtrTimeRecorded")
    lblFtrTimeRecorded.Text = Date.Now

    'Get The Sunday of Current Week and put into label
    Dim lblFtrWeekStart As Label = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("lblFtrWeekStart")
    Dim myDate As Date = DateTime.Today
    Dim dayDiff As Integer = myDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday
    Dim currentDay As Date = myDate.AddDays(-dayDiff) 'Sunday

    For i = 1 To 7
        Console.WriteLine(currentDay)
        'Do something with current day
        currentDay = myDate.AddDays(-myDate.DayOfWeek)
        lblFtrWeekStart.Text = currentDay

    Next

    'Disable edit button if not the current week
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim lbl As Label
        lbl = CType(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("lblWeekStart"), Label)
        If lbl.Text <> currentDay Then
            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Here's the .aspx code for the template field that contains the linkbuttons:

```
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                        Text="Update" ></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                        Text="Cancel" ></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this record?');" />
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                        Text="Edit" ></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see that label anywhere in your markup.

Comment: lblWeekStart is a label in the itemtemplate of the gridview (if that's what you're referring to).

Comment: So your saying you can see it in the above markup?

Comment: If you use `AutoGenerateEditButton = True` the edit button is done for you and the update and cancel buttons are placed for you as well when your in the edit mode.

Comment: yep, i have the buttons, i just need edit to be disabled based on the date in lblweekstart (which i have done successfully), the problem is now that i've done that, the update and cancel linkbuttons now throw the error... so something about adding that code to disable the edit button based on the date in the label made me lose update/cancel functionality

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is this line is returning `Nothing`

```
lbl = CType(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("lblWeekStart"), Label)
```

Hence the following line will thrown an exception because `lbl = Nothing`

```
If lbl.Text <> currentDay Then
```

Looking at the template code it appears there is nothing named "lblWeekStart" available to find.  This means `FindControl` is return `Nothing` as expected.  You need to switch the code to look for the correct ID or change the place where you are searching for "lblWeekStart"

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WeekStart" SortExpression="WeekStart">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblEditWeekStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WeekStart") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFtrWeekStart" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWeekStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WeekStart") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: @Tonigafa based on this code it doesn't appear to be, or at least not within each row or not an instance of `Label`

Comment: sorry it came through all jumbled, but that's where the label is in my gridview template... what am i missing here?

Comment: @Tonigafa isn't that in the header though?  Your code is searching in the rows

Comment: that field is in the itemtemplate

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWeekStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("WeekStart") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

Comment: @Tonigafa please edit you post with relevant code/markup - do not put it in a comment - it is horrible to read.

Comment: @Tonigafa ahh but the is the value directly in the row or a nested control?  FindControl will only search one level

Comment: it must be searching the itemtemplate level, which is why it works upon the initial page load, but the problem comes when i click edit... apparently it can't find it anymore when you click edit? how do you overcome that?